# Python: no results using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a text file with many lines such as:

```
Total:4CASES      gross weight(KG):76          net weight(KG):60          volume(CBM):0.99
Total:203CASES    gross weight(KG):16695.88    net weight(KG):15329.37    volume(CBM):99.29
Total:198CASES    gross weight(KG):14892.25    net weight(KG):13347.77    volume(CBM):105.14
Total:231CASES    gross weight(KG):18730.56    net weight(KG):16825.96    volume(CBM):112.77
```

I'm trying to extract the numbers and get the total of cases, weights and volume.

For the total cases I use the following expression on each line of the file:

```
matchTotalCases = re.search(r'Total:\w*CASES\s', line)
```

When I go `matchTotalCases.group()` it gives me `Total:4CASES` for the first line. That's ok for me, but for gross weight I'm trying:

```
matchGrossWeight = re.search(r'^gross\sweight(KG):\w*[.]?[\w]*$', line)
```

But it doesn't return anything...

So how could I tweak my regex so I get a result like `gross weight(KG):76` or even better, only 76 directly?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: `^` in a regex means beginning of a line. `gross` is not at the beginning of any line, so it won't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expressions have several issues. Take a look at the regular expression syntax documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

1. Your regular expression for `matchGrossWeight` starts with the character `^`, which will match **only** at the beginning of the string, or at the beginning of each line with [`re.MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE).
2. You need to escape parentheses (`()`) to use them as literal characters in a regular expression.
3. Your way of matching numbers with a decimal point is rather awkward. You can simply use `\.` to match a literal `.` character.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the `^` and `$` as they work for line starts and ends, respectively.
2. Escape the `(` and `)`
3. Deal with the numbers in a right way.

Here's a working example for you:

```
matchGrossWeight = re.search(r'gross\sweight\(KG\):[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?', line)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your regexpr, replace `\w*` with `(\d+)`

Comment: That will not make any difference. `\w*` will match anything that `\d+` matches, since digits `[0-9]` are a subclass of "word" characters (normally `[A-Za-z0-9_]`).

Comment: I am looking for digits, not for alphabetic values, so there is a significant difference

Comment: I know that there is a difference between the two, but it won't solve the OP's problem. His regexes don't match **at all**, whereas your answer is to make the matching condition **more strict**. It's a reasonable suggestion, but won't solve his immediate problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Total:(\d+)|gross\s*weight\(KG\):(\d+)
```

Try this .See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hJ7nT4/5

your regex

`matchGrossWeight = re.search(r'^gross\sweight(KG):\w*[.]?[\w]*$', line)` has no escaped '('.
Please escape it by `\`.

Answer (score 0):

```
gross\s+weight\(KG\):(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

This regex will match decimal numbers as well.
The problem with your regex is that `^` matches line beginnings. In addition, parantheses have a special meaning so they have to be escaped.

**Demo**: http://regex101.com/r/jR9zX9/1

In Python, you can use this syntax for your regex:

```
re.search(r'gross\sweight\(KG\):([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)', line).group(1)
```

`group(1)` will return the number only.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to get just the value associated with gross weight:

```
>>> regex = re.compile("gross weight\(KG\)\:(\d+\.*\d+)",re.MULTILINE)
```

The above code on the following input string:

```
gross weight(KG):76
gross weight(KG):16695.88
```

gives:

```
>>> regex = re.compile("gross weight\(KG\)\:(\d+\.*\d+)",re.MULTILINE)
>>> regex.findall(string)
[u'76', u'16695.88']
```

If you are parsing your data one line at a time, then then `re.MULTILINE` argument is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to capture each of the groups, you can also try [this solution](http://regex101.com/r/oA2eZ9/1):

```
(?P<total>(?<=Total:)\d+(?=CASES))
.*?
(?P<gross_weight>(?<=gross\ weight\(KG\):)\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
.*?
(?P<net_weight>(?<=net\ weight\(KG\):)\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
.*?
(?P<volume>(?<=volume\(CBM\):)\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

This will give you results similar to:

`` MATCH 1
    total   [6-7]   `4`
    gross_weight    [35-37] `76`
    net_weight  [62-64] `60`
    volume  [86-90] `0.99`
MATCH 2
    total   [97-100]    `203`
    gross_weight    [126-134]   `16695.88`
    net_weight  [153-161]   `15329.37`
    volume  [177-182]   `99.29`
MATCH 3
    total   [189-192]   `198`
    gross_weight    [218-226]   `14892.25`
    net_weight  [245-253]   `13347.77`
    volume  [269-275]   `105.14`
MATCH 4
    total   [282-285]   `231`
    gross_weight    [311-319]   `18730.56`
    net_weight  [338-346]   `16825.96`
    volume  [362-368]   `112.77` ``

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?P<total>(?<=Total:)\d+(?=CASES)).*?(?P<gross_weight>(?<=gross\ weight\(KG\):)\d+(?:\.\d+)?).*?(?P<net_weight>(?<=net\ weight\(KG\):)\d+(?:\.\d+)?).*?(?P<volume>(?<=volume\(CBM\):)\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)
test_str = u"Total:4CASES      gross weight(KG):76          net weight(KG):60          volume(CBM):0.99\nTotal:203CASES    gross weight(KG):16695.88    net weight(KG):15329.37    volume(CBM):99.29\nTotal:198CASES    gross weight(KG):14892.25    net weight(KG):13347.77    volume(CBM):105.14\nTotal:231CASES    gross weight(KG):18730.56    net weight(KG):16825.96    volume(CBM):112.77\n"
re.findall(p, test_str)
```